# Dynamically add a form_tag using jQuery in Rails 3.2

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My app has a user dashboard that lists rules a user has created.  Each rule can be added to a "ruleset".  For each rule, I want to display a button that when clicked, loads a form that allows the user to add that rule to a ruleset.

I have the following code in my view to show each rule:

```
<% @rules.each do |rule| %>
  <div class="rule-wrapper">

    <div class="rule-content row">
      <div class="span6">
        <strong>Rule:</strong> <%= rule.description %>
      </div>
      <div class="span2">           
        <div class="add-to-ruleset-form">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  ......
```

The pertinent part of my Rules controller is as follows:

```
class RulesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def add_rule_to_ruleset
    @ruleset = Ruleset.find(params[:ruleset_id])
    @rule = Rule.find(params[:rule_id])

    @ruleset.rule << @rule

  end

  ....
```

Lastly, here is what my dashboard.js.erb file looks like:

```
$('.add-to-ruleset').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.add-to-ruleset-form').html('<%= escape_javascript(link_to render :partial =>   "add_to_ruleset_form", :locals => {:rule => rule}) %>')
});
```

I'd like that when a button ('add-to-ruleset') is clicked, that the partial is rendered.  I've tried using "escape_javascript" helper in my js.erb file but it isn't passing the "rule" variable corrent.  I've also tried to use jQuery's load(), but I don't know how to pass the "rule" instance variable to the partial using jQuery.  Is there another way?

Comment: Would you mind to share your controller code as well?

Comment: I've added the important part of my Rules controller to the initial question.

Comment: You are doing things wrong way. Better you check http://railsdog.com/blog/2011/02/28/callbacks-in-jquery-ujs-in-rails3/ and http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/ to get more idea